# MS Chart not showing on hosted site

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I have a MS Chart component displaying fine on an ASP.Net page. When I deploy it I get a broken image.  The settings in the web.config are the same and the temporary images folder has the correct permissions.

When I get the URL of the images I can see that the /.png file is not getting created.

What sort of things do I need to look at to track down the problem?

Comment: what .NET version are you running? in 3.5 you have to install chart for 3.5sp1 while in 4.0 it's already in. + you could "OFF" the custom errors on the deployed machine to see the error.

Comment: Using .Net4.   There are no errors produced.  Just the chart displays as a broken image on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by ensuring that my application pool settings was using "ASP .net integrated" and not "ASP .Net Classic".  This will ensure that your handler is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was working with the charting in .NET 4 and my problem turned out to be related to the default value of the privateImages attribute and the fact that my code wasn't using any identifying attributes for the session or the user.

See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933830/asp-net-charting-control-not-working-on-production-server) for an explanation of how I solved my problem.

It's also worth noting that the ASP.NET Development server ignores the config settings for charting and renders them in memory unless you specifically set an attribute to force it to use your config.